# mips assembly code, logical operations using shift functions

Tags: assembly, rotation, mips, logical-operators, bit-shift

So here is the assignment and then below that are my questions and code I have so far.

> Write a program that loads four signed integer operands (A, B, C, and D) from memory into registers,
>
> shifts and rotates instructions to multiply the value of A by 5,
>
> divide the value of B by 4 (truncating the result),
>
> then shifts the value of C to the right 3 bit places and
>
> rotates the value of D 2 bit places to the left.
>
> Finally, the program will write the new values of A, B, C, and D back to memory.
>
> Be sure to test your program carefully, using both positive and negative integers for inputs. Validate correct program operation by examining the updated contents of the memory operands. Do NOT use multiply or divide instructions! (HINT: 5A = 4A + A.)
>
> Please include C code for each line if possible. Thanks!

---

1. I can not figure out how to multiply by an odd number, I know I need to multiply to get as close as I can an add 1, but I dont cant figure out how to do that.
2. This code I will paste below which I have so far works for B, C and D....for both positive and negative numbers, however in the I/O section Mars prints the result I ask for then says -- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --. What does that mean and how do I fix it.
3. I am not sure B is actually truncating the result, please confirm or correct and explain. Thanks.....below is my code so far.

---

```
.text

main:

lw $t0, A
lw $t1, B
lw $t2, C
lw $t3, D

sll $s0, $t0, 2 # A= 5*4=20

sra $s1, $t1, 2 # B= -44/4=-11

sra $s2, $t2, 3 # C= -128/8=-16

rol $s3, $t3, 2 # D= -8 becomes -29

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s3 # system call to print and check results
syscall

.data # the .data directive starts the data section

A: .word 5
B: .word -44
C: .word -128
D: .word -8

li $v0, 10 # exit
syscall
```

Comment: Why is there code in the `.data` section?

Comment: Perhaps the code in `.data` is why he's getting the "dropped off bottom" error.

Comment: Should the A: .word (value) be above the code under main

Comment: Do I even need the data section?

Comment: Wait a sec.....The data section is where I declare my integer-sized variable by .word right?  What do you mean why is there code, that's where the code goes.  Correct me If I am wrong this is my first coding assignment but that's basic right?

Answer (score 2):

After the sll $s0, $t0, 2 , $s0 = 20, not 25, since it's $t0 << 2. Just like the hint states, you need to do an add as well.

Comment: Right but for A the instruction says shifts and rotates instructions to multiply the value of A by 5.   So dont I also have to rotate in order to multiply.  So two lines of code, one shifts and one rotates.  I get the hint is add.  So if A = 10 I multiply by 4 and get 40 then add 10, but I do this using a rotate right?

Comment: You can't multiply by 5 using only shifts/rotates. You'll have to use shift + add like the hint suggests. If the instructions are unclear, ask your professor / lab supervisor about it.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think I need to use the store word function (sw) because according to the instructions it says "Write a program that loads four signed integer operands (A, B, C, and D) from memory into registers.....perform operations......Finally, the program will write the new values of A, B, C, and D back to memory

Comment: My code is now as follows: '....my code is now as follows `

`      lw $t0, A          
       lw $t1, B          
       lw $t2, C
       lw $t3, D

       sll $s0, $t0, 2       # A= 5*4=20
       addi $s0, $s0, 5      # A=(5*4)+5=25
       sra $s1, $t1, 2       # B= -44/4=-11
       sra $s2, $t2, 3       # C= -128/8=-16
       rol $s3, $t3, 2       # D= -8 becomes -29 
      

 `

Comment: For A it should be sll $s0,$t0,2 # addi $s0,$t0

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, where you said the program says "however in the I/O section Mars prints the result I ask for then says -- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --. What does that mean and how do I fix it."

Understand that MARS (Compiler used to run the MIPS instructions) runs the whole code in a single direction fashion, starts reading from the .text section and keeps going downwards till it finds no more code to read. If not exited properly, it like drops off from the last line of code and exits in a no so graceful fashion.

In your case you have your syscall 10 instruction in the data section. Put the syscall 10 instruction in the .text section, that is right above your .data section so that program doesn't drop off the bottom. Hope that helped